# How to access stdclass object in php

Tags: php

Can anyone tell me how to access name from below code :

How to access stdclass object

```
stdClass Object
(
    [formdata] => [{"name":"aaa"},{"designation":""},{"organization":""},{"country":""},{"email":""},{"phone":""},{"status":""},{"interest":[]},{"comment":""},{"radio":""}]
)
```

Comment: Please output your object with the function var_export(). This makes it easier to reproduce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it like this

```
$obj = stdClass Object
(
 [formdata] => [{"name":"aaa"},{"designation":""},{"organization":""},{"country":""},{"email":""},{"phone":""},{"status":""},{"interest":[]},{"comment":""},{"radio":""}]
)

$newdata = json_decode(json_encode($obj), True);
$data =  json_decode($newdata['formdata'], True);
echo '<pre>';print_r($data);
 die;
```

it will give you and array and you can access each variables

Comment: try this way around then json_decode(json_encode($data), true);

Comment: I have tested this as well